# T-SQL Query null issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a stored procedure which will return true or false based on the following condition:

- if 2 columns in all the rows in a result set are null, then return true
- if at least one is not null, then return false

Like for example in the following query

```
select * 
from Products 
where productID = 123 
  and ProductType is null 
  and ProductDate is null
```

The above query can return 1 row or return 100 rows, so if all are null, then it will return true; if at least 1 is not null, then it will return false.

Comment: Procedures in SQL Server don't return anything (except for maybe some status flag) and there is no Boolean data type, i.e. no true or false. So there's quite some room for interpretation in your question. You should elaborate.

Comment: when i said true or false I meant 0 or 1  so basically it will be Set @result=1 or Set result=0

Comment: So you don't care how many rows are returned and you don't really want the two additional where clauses - if any value of either ProductType or ProductDate is _not null_, you want to return false, but you want to return true if _every single value_ for ProductType and ProductDate are NULL?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i want to return true if every single value for ProductType and ProductDate are NULL in every row that the query returns

Answer (score 1):

Given this sample data and desired results:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products
(
  ProductID int,
  ProductType int,
  ProductDate date
);

INSERT dbo.Products(ProductID, ProductType, ProductDate)
  VALUES
  (123, NULL, NULL),(123, NULL, NULL), -- this should return 1
  (456, 5, NULL),   (456, NULL, NULL), -- this should return 0
  (789, NULL, GETDATE());              -- this should return 0
```

We can do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever1
  @ProductID int
AS   
BEGIN
  DECLARE @return int = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Products 
    WHERE productID = @ProductID
      AND (ProductType IS NOT NULL OR ProductDate IS NOT NULL)
  ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;

  RETURN @return;
END
```

Then to execute:

```
DECLARE @hr int;
EXEC @hr = dbo.whatever1 @ProductID = 123;
SELECT @hr;
EXEC @hr = dbo.whatever1 @ProductID = 456;
SELECT @hr;
EXEC @hr = dbo.whatever1 @ProductID = 789;
SELECT @hr;
```

Results:

```
1
0
0
```

The tricky bit is when you say "return" we're not quite sure if you mean the explicit `RETURN` keyword, or an `OUTPUT` parameter, or a resultset. I feel like an `OUTPUT` parameter would be more appropriate in this case, since `RETURN` is generally reserved for error/status (and can only be an `int`). So we can use a more appropriate type depending on what we need:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever2
  @ProductID int,
  @return bit OUTPUT
AS  
BEGIN
  SET @return = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Products 
    WHERE productID = @ProductID
      AND (ProductType IS NOT NULL OR ProductDate IS NOT NULL)
  ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
END
```

Then to execute:

```
DECLARE @return bit;
EXEC dbo.whatever2 @ProductID = 123, @return = @return OUTPUT;
SELECT @return;
EXEC dbo.whatever2 @ProductID = 456, @return = @return OUTPUT;
SELECT @return;
EXEC dbo.whatever2 @ProductID = 789, @return = @return OUTPUT;
SELECT @return;
```

Results:

```
1
0
0
```

- Working example here (though be aware that fiddle displays `bit` as `true`/`false` instead of `1`/`0`): [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aab2973a90086b53acbc031886561607)

If either of these procedures don't work like you expect, please adjust the fiddle with your sample data that you think is producing wrong results, and please be specific about what you mean by "return" and "always give me a value of" - we have no idea where you are seeing `1` and why you would expect to see `0`.

Comment: I tried your solution above, but it always give me a value of 1. Can you show me sample data on which I can try this query

Comment: @CertGuy if the examples don’t work for you, then YOU please provide some sample data that you think produces incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select IIF(COUNT(*) = 0, 'true','false')
from Products 
where productID=@ProductID and ProductType is null and ProductDate is null
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it always returns false

Comment: @CertGuy how are you determining what is being "returned"?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Products WHERE ProductID = 123 AND (ProductType IS NOT NULL OR ProductDate IS NOT NULL))`

`SELECT CAST (0 AS bit)`

`ELSE`

`SELECT CAST (1 AS bit)`

Using exists is more efficient than a count since it will only scan the table until the condition is met. Count will always scan the whole table.